# How do I crate a plane(or object) that is invisible but can catch light(cycles)?

Tags: rendering, particles, transparency, lighting, shader-nodes

So I have went through alot of Answers and Questions about this, but could not really find a desired solution. I currently have a Particle Emitter creating Light on a plane in my scene.

However, I need that plane to be invisible, so that I can have the light of the particles on an invisible plane(simply so that when using it for irl videoproduction I can use the invisible plane as the ground in the video)

Here is a picture of my scene(rendered). (I gave the plane a blue color only to know when it is tranparent and when not):
[image]

I have heard of and used shadow catchers before, but of course they don't do the job, since, I only need to catch light.
I do not have a problem, if I have to change the plane into an 3d object for that.

Thanks in advance.
Hoping for help.